# I (think) I'm getting objects returned when I expect my array to have just 2 properties available

Tags: ruby, oop, blackjack

Probably the worst way to ask a question, but I'm new and trying my best to explain my problem.

I'm implementing a Ruby Blackjack game. You can see the repo / source for what I have here: https://bitbucket.org/subem81/blackjack

This is the particular section of concern (kept in the "Hand" module which is included in the Dealer and Player classes using what I think are mixins):

```
def show_hand
    if self.class.to_s == 'Dealer'
        self.hand.each do |card|
            card.show_card
        end
    elsif self.class.to_s == 'Player'

    else
        puts "A Random person is showing their hand."
    end

end
```

Which calls the show_card() method for each Card object. Or so I thought. I keep getting no method errors on the card objects. Here is that error:

```
$ ruby blackjack.rb
Welcome to Mike's Blackjack.
blackjack.rb:35:in `block in show_hand': undefined method `show_card' for 
[# <Card:0x007fe504110918 @suit="Spades", @card_type="King">]:Array (NoMethodError)
from blackjack.rb:34:in `each'
from blackjack.rb:34:in `show_hand'
from blackjack.rb:21:in `setup_players'
from blackjack.rb:6:in `initialize'
from blackjack.rb:116:in `new'
from blackjack.rb:116:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Since you are new to Ruby I just wanted to point out that you can just write `if self.class == Dealer` instead of converting the class to a string.

Comment: There’s no point in using a module like this if you’re just going to switch on which class it’s in. Just implement the different behavior in each class.

Comment: andrew.cuthbert - Thanks for the pointer! @AndrewMarshall I agree about the module. I used it just to reinforce the concept for myself here. I realize is violates the purpose of modules since it's individualized to each other class that uses it. Are there other style type issues that you see? That's not sarcastic, I would seriously like any input you all have since I'm basically teaching myself these principles. Thank all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Deck.give_card you are returning cards_sent via pop with an argument.   This returns an array.  So the dealer and player hands will be an array of arrays of cards.  (pop without an argument returns a single item.)

From your error:

> undefined method `show_card' for [# ]:**Array**

You can change:

```
            @dealer.hand << @deck.give_card
            @player.hand << @deck.give_card
            @dealer.hand << @deck.give_card
            @player.hand << @deck.give_card
```

to:

```
            @dealer.hand += @deck.give_card
            @player.hand += @deck.give_card
            @dealer.hand += @deck.give_card
            @player.hand += @deck.give_card
```

Or rename your give_card to give_cards and add a new give_card:

```
    def give_card
      @cards.pop
    end
```

Comment: Wow.. Thanks Shawn! I even looked at the docs and failed to notice the different types returned or even consider it. This was a great help. Thank you!